# Can't install packages to nix-build project

Tags: reflex

After running `nix-build -o frontend-result -A ghcjs.frontend` for obelist project it errors for several imports one of which is:

```
src/Frontend.hs:10:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Trans’
    Perhaps you meant
      Control.Monad.Fail (from base-4.11.1.0)
      Control.Monad.Fix (from base-4.11.1.0)
      Control.Monad.ST (from base-4.11.1.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

After which I try to install the package with `cabal new-install Control`

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: backend-0.1 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: obelisk-route (dependency of backend)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: backend, obelisk-route)
```

Answer (score 3):

Both reflex and obelix use cabal to declare dependencies but actually install them via nix. Therefore you're suppose to add mtl package, with the example above, to frontend.cabal under field build-depends.